# Posting object using ajax to PHP

Tags: json, object

I'm trying to post to php using ajax.
I can't seem to figure why the data isn't been posted.
The console.log shows 'success'.

var obj shown is for check only.
the code:

```js
  var obj = {'age':'32'};
  obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
  
  
  $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: {'phpobj': obj},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
    //do whatever.
    console.log('success');
   }
  });
```

and the php (in the same url):

```html
  if (isset($_POST['phpobj'])) {
   echo 'phpobj is POSTED:</br></br>';
   $php_obj = $_POST['phpobj'];
   $decoded = json_decode($php_obj, true);
   var_dump($decoded);
  } else {
   echo 'phpobj Wasnt POSTED';
  }
```

Thanks for helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing your code like this

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {'age': 32},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        //do whatever.
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

PHP

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        echo 'REQUEST is POSTED:</br></br>';
        $age= $_POST['age'];
        var_dump($_POST);exit;
   } else {
        echo 'phpobj Wasnt POSTED';
   }
```

Change the rest according to your requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i encounterd the same problem before, i gave up using ajax to post.
you can use the jquery to create a form then let the user submit it to php.

Comment: How? Can you share an example?